# Graceful shutdown и запросы в состоянии обработки

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Реализовываю Graceful shutdown на ASP.NET Core 2.1. Заметил, что при вызове SIGINT или Ctrl+C в консоли все запросы, которые обрабатываются в данный момент, прерываются. Соответственно, если Controller через свои Action выполняет какие-либо запросы в DB без транзакций, система может оказаться в неконсистентном состоянии.

Из описания IApplicationLifetime https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Рассмотрим событие **ApplicationStopping**

> **ApplicationStopping** Triggered when the application host is performing a graceful shutdown. Requests may still be in flight.
>   Shutdown will block until this event completes.

Я ожидал, что сервак дождется завершения обработки текущих запросов, запретив приходить новым. В реальности же он вырубается несмотря на существующие запросы.

Как дождаться завершения текущих запросов?

**Пример:**

```
   public static void Main(string[] args) { 
        WebHostExtensions.Run(BuildWebHost(args));
    }

    private static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) {
        return WebHostExtensions.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:9100")
            .Build();
    }
```

Контроллер:

```
public class UserOrdersController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserOrders(string productId)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        //.....................................
    }        
}
```

**"Finished" не будет выведено, если послать сигнал о завершении.**

Comment: Да вроде должен дожидаться (но не дольше чем ShutdownTimeout). Вы можете привести [mcve]?

Comment: @PavelMayorov пример добавил

Comment: кажется, 5000 - слишком большое число для тайм-аута по умолчанию

Comment: "Some connections failed to close gracefully during server shutdown" - такая ошибка в консоли. Я не смог найти, где этот ShutdownTimeout конфигурировать в .net core 2.1

Comment: @PavelMayorov
Добавил `.UseShutdownTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))` в билдер, но это не помогло.